# Orange PI PC +Android 4.4.2 (kernel 3.4.39) подружить с UART GPS

Tags: android, gps, orange-pi

Собственно имеется плата [Orange PI PC](http://www.orangepi.org/orangepipc/) для разрабочиков на процессоре Allwinner H3. На устройство установлен [Android 4.4.2](http://www.orangepi.org/downloadresources/orangepipc/oragepipc_6ace8597a2051c8bcf2b9e7b63.html) (kernel 3.4.39) от разработчика платы. Соответственно версия сильно порезана, многое убрано. Имеется в наличии GPS приёмник с UART интерфейсом. Что нужно доустановить (или допилить), чтобы программы навигации увидели данные с приёмника и полноценно работали. По команде в терминале cat /dev/ttyS3 идёт поток NMEA.
Что в андроиде обрабатывает эти данные и куда передаёт. Какие библиотеки за это отвечают.

Я добавил файл android.hardware.location.gps.xml в /system/etc/permission с правами 644.
Я поместил библиотеку gps.defaul.so в /system/lib/hw с правами 644.
В build.prop добавил строки:

```
ro.kernel.android.gps = ttyS3
ro.kernel.android.gps.speed = 9600
ro.factory.hasGPS = true
```

На ttyS3 через скрипт в init.d также выставляю права 666.
GPS test пишет: GPS_ON и NO_FIX
Но при этом ничего не принимает.
Скорость порта-9600, скорость приёмника-9600.
Также пробовал подключать через USB.
cat /dev/ttyUSB0 отдаёт поток NMEA

PS Понимаю, что вопрос глупый. Но в андроиде я полный ноль.